# Connect to socket with path

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket

I have found in internet that it is possible to connect to websocket in a following way:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("foo.com");    
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
```

But I need an adress with a following path

```
foo.pl/armchair/rest/message/device
```

Not just foo.com like in example above.

How to modify this example code to include path part /armchair/rest/message/device

Comment: Implement the *HTTP protocol* as that's an HTTP URL, i.e. connect and issue an HTTP GET request which is where the resource URI is specified. (there are other headers you should include as well)

Comment: Oops I missed the websocket tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo.pl/armchair/rest/message/device
```

Well, connection should be made to foo.p1 because it is the actual name of the server which can be resolved by the DNS. `"/armchair/rest/message/device"`, now this is the path in the server. Now if you want specific file in that path, connect to the server at "foo.p1" and use GET method to get the file in the specific path. You can construct a GET request like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881613/writing-proper-head-and-get-request-in-winsock-c) and you are done. :)